# Create array of URL values using jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, url

I have a number of values that are being passed via the URL, that I need to capture in an array, to replace text elements on a page. For example:

URL: http://www.domain.com/?client=ClientName&project=ProjectName

I'm looking to have a simple piece of html which will have the values inserted. For example

```
<ul>
  <li>Client: <span class="client"></span></li>
  <li>Project: <span class="project"></span></li>
</ul>
```

This should produce:

- Client: ClientName
- Project: ProjectName

It is possible that the pieces of data will need to be written a number of times on a page, hence the use of the span tags with classes.

Can anyone advise as to how this can be achieved using jQuery. Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do this on the server side? That would be so much simpler...

Comment: The final page is a static HTML file. I'm just looking to pop in some personalised content & presumed this would be the simplest way to achieve it. What alternative do you suggest?

Comment: `var params = jquery.param(object)`   http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/8WTA6/2/

```
var params = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var param = params[i].split('=');
    $("." + param[0]).html(param[1]);
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic thanks! This is a little beyond my current understanding of the code. Any chance you could point me to some relevant documentation so I can read up. Thanks again.

Comment: Let's take a look. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp - here is about `location` object. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp - here is about splitting string to array of strings. We're doing it twice: first time to split by "&" and get "key=value" strings, second - to split it by "=". http://api.jquery.com/html/ is about `.html()` and http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/ is about class selector. Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much for your help!! Just quickly, so that I can get this to work with elements that have spaces (i.e. "Client Name"). I presume I can use decodeURI but I'm not sure how to integrate it in the above. Can you advise??? (bit cheeky I know)